# systemInfo.machine value for iPad 2 and latest iPod

Tags: iphone, ios

I dont have access to these devices, but my app needs to test which device it is running on. Can anyone tell me the values of systemInfo.machine on iPad 2, and the latest iTouch (with camera)?

The values I have already are:

@"i386"  on the simulator

@"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch

@"iPhone1,1" on iPhone

@"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G

@"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS

@"iPad1,1"   on iPad

@"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iPad2,1 (product ID ?, hex ?, hw.model K93AP): iPad 2 WiFi
iPad2,2 (product ID ?, hex ?, hw.model K94AP): iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (GSM)
iPad2,3 (product ID ?, hex ?, hw.model K95AP): iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (CDMA)
iPod4,1 (product ID 4766, hex 0x129e, hw.model N81AP): iPod Touch "4G"
```

Source: http://www.edepot.com/iphone.html#iPhone_Product_Code